# Magento2 retrieve custom customer attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, plugin, customer-attribute

i'm working on a 2.1.9 magento2 CE installation,

i've added a custom attribute to the customer, everything it's working OK, but when the attribute is not set and I try to retrieve it with the code

$customer->getCustomAttributes()["custom_field"]->getValue() I get an exception, instead a null value.

if the attribute is set on the customer this method will retur the correct data.

the exception is this one:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: custom_field in /var/www/magento/[INSTALLATION_DIR]/app/design/frontend/[TEMPLATE_DIR]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/edit.phtml on line 33

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: custom_field in /var/www/magento/[INSTALLATION_DIR]/app/design/frontend/[TEMPLATE_DIR]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/edit.phtml on line 33
```

in phtml files right now i'm working with a try catch block to avoid the exception, but when I'm working on a plugin the exception will stop the execution even in a try catch block.

any suggestion to check if custom attribute exist?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Templates are not responsible for handle any logic, so any try catch block inside of template is a blasphemy.

Put your logic in block. I imagine you can do something like:

```
public function getCustomfield()
{
    return !empty($customer->getCustomAttributes()["custom_field"]) ? $customer->getCustomAttributes()["custom_field"]->getValue() : '';
}
```

Then call it in your template.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The `Notice: Undefined index` has nothing to do with the code being executed in a template.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in phtml:

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_helper->getCustomerAttributeValue($this->getCustomer()->getId(), 'custom_field')); ?>
```

`Helper.php`

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCustomerAttributeValue($customerId, $attributeCode)
{
    $customerObject = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
    return $customerObject->getData($attributeCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar issue the reason was a wrong configuration of the attribute.

I created the attribute in an `UpgradeData` script like this:

```php
$this->customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'blacklisted', [
    'label' => 'Customer is blacklisted',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => 0,
    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
]);
```

The problem is that customer attributes have the `system` option set to `true` per default. This prevents the attribute from being added to the `custom_attributes` array in the customer's data. You can find more details about that [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269313/31734).

What I had to do was adding `'system' => false` to the option array.

After that don't forget to clear the cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```