# How to prevent "Call to a member function getValue() on null" when using getCustomAttribute()->getValue()?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

My colleague wrote some code, which is hidden behind an interface:

```
$myCustomValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue();
```

Working on integrations now, I invoke his code via an API and just came across customers who do not have a value set for that attribute.

The error message I get is:

```
Call to a member function getValue() on null
```

How can I modify his code best, so that it checks first if the value is set for the specific customer?

Comment: Please use : `$myCustomValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute');`

Comment: Also try this : `$customer->getData('my_custom_attribute');`

Comment: Check my answer will help you to get value.

Comment: Check that attribute exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try following way:

```
if($myCustomAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')) {
    echo $myCustomAttribute->getValue();
}
```

Comment: This one works for me.

Comment: Subjective, but urgh assignment in condition...

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
if(null !== $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute'))
{
  $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue();
}
```

Comment: This one works for me.

Comment: Subjective, but urgh yoda conditions...

Answer (score 2):

**To get the customer attribute, you can use like this:**

```
if($customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')) 
{
   $attrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue();
   echo $attrValue;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this one return an AttributeInterface? I need the value...

Comment: This is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer custom attribute using below code:

```
<?php
namespace Amitshree\Marketplace\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {  
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $customerId = 5;
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $customerAttributeData = $customer->__toArray();
        $isVendor = $customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['is_vendor']['value'];
        echo "<pre>";print_r($customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']);exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, a nice alternative approach. I think in this case we should add some issets:  if (isset($customerAttributeData['custom_attributes'])) && isset($customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['is_vendor']) ...otherwise we might run into the same problem with the undefined indexes (depending on php settings).

Answer (score 0):

This happens with products as well, if you create a custom attribute and don't set values against this attribute for products, then getting these attribute against such products will return null.

To avoid running into error, always make a check before calling a custom attribute to make sure if its value is set or not.

e.g Something like this should work.

```
if($customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute') !== null && $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue() !== null) {
    echo $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, - but is the second condition ($customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue() !== null) really necessary to query for?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I tried to access a custom attribute that I have created with an `UpdateData` script.

The reason was that attributes are created as system attributes per default. You have to set the `system` option to `false` explicitly.

Example:

```php
$this->customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'blacklisted', [
    'label' => 'Customer is blacklisted',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => 0,
    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
    'system' => false, // <-- Notice this line!
]);
```

Checkout [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269313/31734) for more information about the system option.