# Creating a new attribute to Customer Entity - Throwing Error

Tags: magento2.4, customer-attribute

I am creating a new attribute (mobile) for the Customer Entity. The attribute should be of type 'static' since this one is a required field and for easy retrieval.

I came to know that it requires 2 steps:

1. Create a column in the customer_entity table.
2. Add an attribute to the customer entity with Patch.

Below is my code:

1. Creating column in customer_entity table. `db_schema.xml`

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="customer_entity">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="mobile" comment="Customer Mobile Number" nullable="false"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Generated scheme whitelist `db_schema_whitelist.json`:

```
{
    "customer_entity": {
        "column": {
            "mobile": true
        }
    }
}
```

2. Created a Data Patch for adding a new attribute in the `eav_attribute` table, `AddMobileAttributePatch.php`:

```
public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'mobile',
            [
                'type'         => 'static',
                'label'        => 'Mobile Number',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => true,
                'unique'       => true,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                                    ->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile')
                                    ->addData([
                                        'used_in_forms' => [
                                            'adminhtml_customer',
                                            'checkout_register',
                                            'customer_account_create',
                                            'customer_account_edit'
                                        ],
                                    ]);

        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
```

Now the column is created in the `customer_entity` table and a new attribute is available in the `eav_attribute` table. The field is also available in the Admin Customer Edit Form.

The problem is when I enter some data into the `mobile` field and hit save, it returns the error `" Mobile Number" is a required value.`. This error is from the server-side and Js validation is working fine.

Can anyone help me get through this?
[image: Magento-customer-entity-attribute-required-error]

Comment: The error comes from the admin or frontend?

Comment: It is from the admin end. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: instead of mobile please try to change attribute code "mobileno"

Comment: @GohilRajesh Is there any attribute named "mobile" in Customer Entity already?

Comment: I think not but please try once by changing name. that will make us more sure

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I tried changing the attribute name to "mobileno", getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Update `is_user_defined` and `system` property to `false`. This is for my specific where I do not want the attribute to be a system value.

The issue was related to below issues:
 [Customer attribute gives error of required value #7753](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7753) 
 [Customer EAV Decimal Attribute required allow 0 #20030](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20030)

During debugging, when the `validateValue($value)` method was called in `Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text`, I was getting empty string for `$value`. But the $_POST does have the newly created attribute value.

Then luckily I found this thread.
[Attribute property 'system' - what it exactly does](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124277/attribute-property-system-what-it-exactly-does)

> \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata::getCustomAttributesMetadata
> These methods are deciding to add or not to add your created attributes to custom_attributes array. It means that these attributes will not be accessible for CRUD operations in Repositories.

Then I changed the `is_user_defined` property to `false` and now the attribute value is getting saved in the DB.